# Download multiple images into zip

Tags: php

I am trying to add functionality to my website where users can download multiple image files via a single `.zip` folder. Currently I have this code executing but when i open the downloaded zip file it extracts another zip file `my-archive (3) 2.zip.cpgz` and every time I try to open it, it extracts yet another zip file.

Here is my basic code using php native zip feature.

```
$image1 = "http://cdn.screenrant.com/wp-content/uploads/Darth-Vader-voiced-by-Arnold-Schwarzenegger.jpg";
$image2 = "http://cdn.screenrant.com/wp-content/uploads/Star-Wars-Logo-Art.jpg";

$files = array($image1, $image2);
$zipname = 'file.zip';
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);
foreach ($files as $file) {
    $zip->addFile($file);
}
$zip->close();

header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$zipname);
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipname));
readfile($zipname);
```

EDIT

I am trying hard to get the provided answer to work. I just tried the most recent edit and got this error

[image: []]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should download external files and then archive them.

```
$image1 = "http://cdn.screenrant.com/wp-content/uploads/Darth-Vader-voiced-by-Arnold-Schwarzenegger.jpg";
$image2 = "http://cdn.screenrant.com/wp-content/uploads/Star-Wars-Logo-Art.jpg";

$files = array($image1, $image2);

$tmpFile = tempnam('/tmp', '');

$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open($tmpFile, ZipArchive::CREATE);
foreach ($files as $file) {
    // download file
    $fileContent = file_get_contents($file);

    $zip->addFromString(basename($file), $fileContent);
}
$zip->close();

header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=file.zip');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($tmpFile));
readfile($tmpFile);

unlink($tmpFile);
```

In example above I used `file_get_contents` function, so please enable `allow_url_fopen` or use curl to download the files.

Comment: Thank for your answer. I'm having the same issue though. I'm using `file_get_contents` as per your example, still not working.

Comment: I checked, works for me. It's possible the issue with permissions, you can try to create temporary file using `tempnam` function.

Comment: I just tried `echo tempnam("/","TMP0");` and it echoed out `/tmp/TMP0hwzkRX` so i can assume the permissions are fine?

Comment: I just tried your latest edit and got an error pop up. I have upload an image of the popup to my edit question.

Comment: It fails when I try to use it with data:url image, which is what I am only using it for. Would you know the best way to implement this with data uri images?

Comment: It's possible to use `base64_decode` function. Examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6417720/create-display-image-from-dataurl  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6735414/php-data-uri-to-file

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys above code worked perfectly. Images download worked only on live server (only if we use https or http). But it is not worked in local (if we use https or http)..
If you use local follow this -> Only change below lines.
For local use below img's
 $image1 = "C:/Users/User/Pictures/Saved Pictures/chandamama.jpg";
 $image2 = "C:/Users/User/Pictures/Saved Pictures/beautifull.jpg";
Do not use below img's for local. 
$image1 = "http://cdn.screenrant.com/wp-content/uploads/Darth-Vader-voiced-by-Arnold-Schwarzenegger.jpg";
$image2 = "http://cdn.screenrant.com/wp-content/uploads/Star-Wars-Logo-Art.jpg";